# $AdS_2/CFT_1$ toy model of a magnetic monopole

Tags: ads-cft, magnetic-monopoles, holographic-principle

Is it possible to create a holographic $AdS_2/CFT_1$ (2D/1D) toy model, which contains a magnetic monopole solution in the bulk?

I would like to study certain behaviours on the boundary of a toy model of this type for a project.

Comment: How do you propose to define a magnetic monopole in 1 spatial dimension? The only independent component of the field strength tensor is $E_1=F_{01}$

Comment: I realized this as well. The problem is that I probably won’t be able to work in AdS3, due to my limited understanding and limited time. I know that it is possible to work entirely in the classical regime  in AdS2, at least in most situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near horizon geometry of four-dimensional extreme Reissner–Nordström geometry is the Bertotti–Robinson solution, which is the $\text{AdS}_2\times S^2$ geometry with Maxwell field. Now, this solution has a magnetic version  and can be analyzed using AdS$_{2}$/CFT$_{1}$ tools.

**References**

- Chen, C. M., Sun, J. R., & Zou, S. J. (2010). *The RN/CFT correspondence revisited*. Journal of High Energy Physics, 2010(1), 1-13, [arXiv:0910.2076](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.2076).
- Castro, A., & Larsen, F. (2009). *Near extremal Kerr entropy from AdS2 quantum gravity*. Journal of High Energy Physics, 2009(12), 037, [arXiv:0908.1121](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1121).